# How to Add Rectangle one after other vertically on Canvas in WPF using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, rectangles

I have a `Canvas` in my WPF application. I am adding the `Rectangle` on button click. The `Width` is Fixed but, `Height` is value entered by user in `TextBox/GridCell`.

When i add rectangle on `Canvas` with specifying `Height`. it adds the rectangle but, it doesnt appear one after other. Any idea?

In .xaml.cs:

```
int width=200;
Reactangle rect;
 static int val=0;
  Protected void Add()
  {
            rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
            rect.Height = Convert.ToInt32(txtheight.Text);
            rect.Width = width;
            Canvas.SetLeft(rect,100);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect,rect.Height);
            rect.Tag = val;
            canvasboard.Children.Add(rect);
            val=val+1;
   }
```

[image]
**This adds Rectangle but not Exactly one after other on canvas.**

```
<Canvas Name="canvasboard" Background="White"  Margin="2">
        </Canvas>
<TextBox Name="txtheight" Width="150"/>
```

**Note: I cant use `WrapPanel` or `StackPanel` for this form.** and want to make changes in existing code.

Help Appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the minimum necessary bits in your .xaml file so we don't have to recreate the scenario from your description?

Comment: hi @RQDQ please check i have modified my code! just add the button..!

Comment: Is this a typo: "rect.Height = txtheight.Text"? because rect.Height requires a double, not a string.

Comment: sorry for inconvinience! i forgot to modify it...modified in post..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your adding is sequential elements vertically into this `Canvas`, you can do it without having to add a new variable in class scope as well.

```
private void Add() {
  rect = new Rectangle {
    Stroke = Brushes.Red,
    StrokeThickness = 1,
    Height = Convert.ToDouble(txtheight.Text),
    Width = width
  };
  Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 100);
  double canvasTop = 0.0;
  if (canvasboard.Children.Count > 0) {
    var lastChildIndex = canvasboard.Children.Count - 1;
    var lastChild = canvasboard.Children[lastChildIndex] as FrameworkElement;
    if (lastChild != null)
      canvasTop = Canvas.GetTop(lastChild) + lastChild.Height + 1;
  }
  Canvas.SetTop(rect, canvasTop);
  rect.Tag = val++;
  canvasboard.Children.Add(rect);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try storing a local variable that maintains the combined height of all Rectangles:

```
    private double _top = 0;

    protected void Add()
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
        rect.Height = double.Parse(txtheight.Text);
        rect.Width = 20;
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, _top);
        _top += rect.Height;
        rect.Tag = val;
        canvasboard.Children.Add(rect);
        val = val + 1;
    }
```

Comment: hey @Richard E this too works but i have used Viv solution...Thanks!